# How to simplify SVG code?

Tags: svg, javafx

Is it possible to simplify / clean up svg code by replacing the use-tags with standard svg elements? Maybe an inkscape plugin? Haven't found anything...

Background: I'm converting some svgs to javafx graphics (.fxz) with javafx's production suite. And the tool doesn't understand the `<use>` element.

Comment: You don't mention what tool you are using, what you have tried already, etc.
I think that at this time you should see your tool vendor and post to their forum.

Comment: @graham: I'm working mainly with inkscape, apache batik and webbased stuff like raphael and dojo, too - but I'm interested in everything that does the job. I thought that maybe there is a little tool out there for that job, a plugin or a script. Could be even done with xslt transformations...

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [Scour - an SVG scrubber](http://www.codedread.com/scour/)

> [Scour](http://www.codedread.com/scour/) is an open-source Python script that aggressively cleans SVG files, removing a lot of 'cruft' that certain tools or authors embed into their documents. The goal of scour is to provide an identically rendered image (i.e. a scoured document should have no discernable visible differences from the original file).

They also have an [extension for Inkscape](http://www.codedread.com/scour/#download_inkscape_extension) as of v.48.  To use it, go to "Save As.." and choose "Optimized .SVG.  Be careful, and check your output, as I've found it can get **too** aggressive.  Take these examples for instance, if they show up...

Good:  [image: Original SVG, only slightly mucked with..]  Bad:  [image: After a harsh "Scouring"]

They claim to have and an [online tool](http://www.planetsvg.com/tools/scour/scra.py/form) that does the same tricks... but as of 6/2011 it was not working.  Hope this helps you clean up those often SCARY looking SVG's.  Sometimes I feel like I'm the only one that realizes what this format is capable of!